# Best practice for creating two tables with references

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am computing a graph with nodes `n1, n2, ...` and edges `(n_i, n_j)`. I would like to store it in two postgresql tables. The first is called `nodes` and has a node id column that is defined by a `node_id SERIAL` column. The seconds is called `edges` and has a column `start_node_id` and `end_node_id` that are references into the nodes table and the node id column.

When I insert the nodes I don't know their node ids. So to insert the corrsponding edges I need to query the node ids that were created when I inserted the nodes. Is there a "neater way" of achieving this? What's is you best practice in a situation like this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to refer to nodes by name, you can insert into `edges` by looking up the `id`s:

```
insert into edges (start_node_id, end_node_id)
    select ns.node_id, ne.node_id
    from (values ('n1', 'n2')) e(start_node_name, end_node_name) join
         nodes ns
         on ns.node_name = e.start_node_name join
         nodes ne
         on ne.node_name = e.end_node_name ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [RETURNING](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-insert.html) to get access to the data you just inserted.

In your other question, you report you're using Python; [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5247685/python-postgres-psycopg2-getting-id-of-row-just-inserted) shows how to access the RETURNING values.

Comment: Interesting. I couldn't get it to work in my context: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59085374/psycopg2-returns-none-when-execute-many-is-combined-with-returning-id

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5247685/python-postgres-psycopg2-getting-id-of-row-just-inserted