# Psycopg2 returns none when execute many is combined with returning id

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I want to insert many values into a table using `execute_values`. I also need the ids of the affected rows. I want to use `RETURNING id`. I have set the `fetch` flag. Still, the result is None.

- postgres 11
- python 3.6.9
- psycopg2 '2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)'

I create a table with

```
CREATE TABLE dummy_table (
    id serial,
    name text,
    age int
);
```

The values and query are

```
values = [('bob', 10), ('alice', 12)]
query = 'INSERT INTO dummy_table (name, age) VALUES %s RETURNING id;'
```

I call execute values like this

```
result = psycopg2.extras.execute_values(cursor, query, values, fetch=True)
connection.commit()
print(result)
> None
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Works for me with the versions I happen to have installed on ubuntu 18.04.  What is your OS, and how did you install all the packages? "psycopg2 '2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)'" how did you obtain this info?

Comment: Please show an end-to-end example, rather than isolated fragments.  Maybe you defined "cursor" wrong or something.